# Crons/Jobs in a Symfony 3 project

Tags: php, symfony, cron

A fonctionnality of my project consists of synchronizing data between two databases in two ways.

- From Interface. (the user clicks a button to start synchronizing)
- Automatically from a cron script.

I added a new Action 'synchronizeAction' in the specified Controller, I managed routes and views and It's working fine.
The problem is with the cron :

1. In which location should I put my cron script ?
2. How to use the method 'synchronizeAction' that I created in the Controller inside that cron ?

I created a service and use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="...">
    <services>
        <service id="soc_ref.synchro_clients" class="SocRefBundle\Services    \SynchroClient">    
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

And I created Services/SynchroClient.php

```
class SynchroClient 
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function synchronize () {
        $ref_db = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $other_db = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('other');

        $sql = ' SELECT active, .... ';
        $statement = $other_db->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();

        foreach ($result as $entity) {
            $client = new Client();
            $client->setActive($entity['active']);

            $ref_db->persist($client);
        }
        $sql_truncate = ' TRUNCATE TABLE client';
        $statement = $ref_db->getConnection()->prepare($sql_truncate);
        $statement->execute();
        $ref_db->flush();

        return new Response('1');
    }

}
```

How can I use / inject the entityManager ? $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); is accessible only in Controllers.

I'm just beginning the symfony developement, thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 3):

If I had to do this, first I would move the business logic to a service. Create a command and the call the service function from the controller and the command. Then configure the cron to call the created command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir, I tried to do that but i had problems. Can you please see my response and tell me what to do?

Comment: You need to create a ContainerAwareCommand. You have more info here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container  Once created you can access to your services from the DI container using $this->getContainer()->get('service_name')